# Implement Interface in OO Haskell

Tags: haskell

In this program there is an interface **IPoint** and a function point (which acts as a class in c++) that implements the interface behaviour. I tried many methods to declare that the function point implements IPoint but could not do so.

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances,UndecidableInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, ScopedTypeVariables, DeriveDataTypeable, TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fcontext-stack=100 #-}

module Point where

import OOHaskell

$(label "read'")
$(label "load")
$(label "incr")


type IPoint a = 
    Record ( Read' :=: IO a
          :*: Load :=: (a-> IO())
          :*: Incr :=: IO()
          :*: HNil)

--point value self = self :: IO (IPoint a)
point value self
    = do
    valueRef <- newIORef value :: IO (IORef Integer)
    returnIO $
         read' .=. readIORef valueRef
     .*. load  .=. (\v -> writeIORef valueRef v)
     .*. incr  .=. modifyIORef valueRef (+1)
     .*. emptyRecord
```

How can i specify that the function point implements IPoint??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
point :: Integer -> b -> IO (IPoint Integer)
```

n.b.

1. Top level type annotations always state the type of a value defined elsewhere (usually immediately afterwards, e.g. `point`), not the type of an expression (e.g. `point value self`).
2. The second argument is not used, hence it can be of any type.
3. Your function does not generate an `IPoint a`, it generates an `IPoint Integer`, because it hardcodes the type of `valueRef` as `IORef Integer`.

I'm not sure that doing OO in Haskell is a good idea. It's certainly not idiomatic.